# Is there a topological space X, which is non-contractible and for which every mapping $S^n → X$ for n ≥ 1 is homotopic to a constant mapping?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

This is a homework question and I would appreciate if someone could check my reasoning. This seems too simple to be true.

**Proof:** Assume there exists $X$ with a non-constant function $f:S^n\rightarrow X$ such that $f\not\simeq c_x$. This implies that $1 = |\pi_0(S^n)|\neq|\pi_0(X)| \implies |\pi_0(X)| \geq 2 \implies X$ is non-contractible.

Comment: From [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#10144): "Your question should be clear without the title. After the title has drawn someone's attention to the question by giving a good description, its purpose is done. **The title is not the first sentence of your question**."

Comment: I can’t make heads or tails of what you’ve said. Are you going to exhibit an $X$ or prove none can exist? If the latter, a proof must suppose $X$ exists with the homotopy conditions and show it must be contractible. What are you doing?

Comment: Do you mean like $X=S^0$?

Comment: The condition does not imply $|\pi_0(X)| \neq 1$.

Comment: Every totally disconnected space has your property. But none of them is contractible, except for single point. In particular every discrete space with at least two points is a counterexample.

Answer (score 2):

Your proof does not make sense. What you try to show is that if there exists $f : S^n \to X$ which is not homotopic to a constant function, then $X$ is not contractible. This is trivial: If $X$ is contractible, then all $\phi : Y \to X$ are homotopic to a constant function. In your "proof" you claim that $X$ is not path-connected (i.e. $\pi_0(X)$ has more than one element), but this is wrong. The identity map on $S^n$ is not null-homotopic, but $S^n$ is  path-connected for $n > 0$.

The Warsaw circle $W$ is an example of a compact metrizable space which is not contractible, but having all $\pi_i(W) = 0$.

See

- [How to show Warsaw circle is non-contractible?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1004837)
- [To show that Warsaw circle is simply connected](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3705688/to-show-that-warsaw-circle-is-simply-connected)
- [Maps into spaces containing a copy of the closed topologist's sine curve](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4305548)